# PHP: How can I str_replace a query of variable content?

Tags: php, variables, str-replace

### Goal

I'm looking for a way to str_replace variable content. So that I can change this:

```
...and in week 1 we saw that...
```

into this:

```
...and in <a href="/?w=1">week 1</a> we saw that...
```

### Thoughts

I know how str_replace works and I could solve it by just running a hundred different queries, each with another week. But what I want is a query that looks for this:

```
'week ' + X
```

So a query that finds every string `'week '` that is followed by a number. Can anyone help me solve this? :)

Tx!

Comment: Look at [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and then you can search for your: `week \d+` and replace it with what you want. (If you get stuck you can always post the code here and I will help you further :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `str_replace` you can use `preg_replace` like as

```
preg_replace('/(week\s?(\d+))/',"<a href='/?w=$2'>$1</a>",$your_string);
```